# How to increase accuracy and decrease loss of my model

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, accuracy, performance, loss

https://jovian.ai/casella0798/badmodel
I created the model above to predict red wine quality. I have 6 classes, from 3 to 8. Dataset is unbalanced, with a lot of classes 5 and 6.
My model performs really bad, with a low accuracy, and a loss that does not decrease under 1.
How can I improve this model?
I tried changing #layers and #neurons, also the batch_size and the learning rate. Any suggestion, also related to hyperparameters optimization?
Dataset is available here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wine+quality it is the red version

Comment: how did you manage imbalance?

Comment: I did not anything. What can I do? Something like SMOTE or undersampling? Or there is some trick to do on the NN?

Comment: re-sampling is a possible solution to imbalance, else weight adjustment (where applicable)

Comment: Are you treating this as an ordinal regression?

Comment: @Dave no I am treating as a multilabel classification using cross entropy loss

Comment: @NikosM. do you mean random weight initialization or Xavier for example? Or weight decay?

Comment: Isn’t it an ordinal problem? Perhaps that’s causing some of the performance failure.

Comment: Classes are numerical: from class 3 to class 8, so 6 classes. @Dave

Comment: Some algorithms can be adjusted unequal weights to handle possible data imbalance however this is not applicable in all cases. NNs do not have this feature

Comment: But there’s an order to them, right?

Comment: Yes, class 3 is the worst, 8 is the best @Dave